# My htaccess file keeps bring up 404 errors

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am not to clued up on these and I'm struggling to get this one working.

I just keep getting 404 errors, can someone give me a hand?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is what I have so far. I'm using the CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled in Apache? where do you get this error? in server or in local machine?

Comment: I'm not sure you need the 3rd line. The last line should do the re-write. Try commenting out the 3rd line.

Comment: i have taken out the third line and still no joy and its server side and i have used the framework before on my hosting so im guessing it should be

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this code in the htaccess file..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

this one works fine at my instance...

Comment: Im using a godaddy hosting and its telling me its enabled , and the above still didnt work! Like i said im not very clued up on this!

Comment: If you installation is in a folder and not on root then you will have to add the folder name to the RewriteBase.

eg: RewriteBase /foldername/

Comment: I added the file name to the / and still no joy ! im baffled

Comment: If your website is in a folder then only you have to add folder name.. else leave it as it is..

Answer (score 0):

This one works fine with my site on goDady

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # This one is important for goDaddy
    RewriteBase /


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    # or you can use like this also 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

My folder Structure was like this

```
/
|
 -->mysite
       |
        -->system (d)
       |
        -->application (d)
       |
        -->.htaccess (f)
       |
        -->index.php (f)
```

and in **`config.php`**

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

in  **`routes.php`**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home"; // whatever default controller
```

**Sometimes GoDaddy takes little time to get update .htaccess, So please give some time for each try. And don’t forget to clear out your browser cache. Ctrl+F5 in Firefox to refresh without cache.**

Comment: @Morby-Raybould have you tried with default codeIgniter application folder? I mean without changing anything. Are you getting 404 error from codeIgniter or apache ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Its work for me. I tested it in XAMP, WAMP on my windows pc as well as in my UBUNTU and CentOS Server. And my codeigniter version is (2.1.0)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this as ur .htaccess file and check mod rewrite is enabled

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

config > config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this.

RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```